# Need help understanding line of decompiled code from ghidra

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I'm reversing a simple binary in Ghidra and have run across the following decompiled C-code:

```
original_key._0_4_ = original_key._0_4_ & 0xffff0000 | (uint)CONCAT11(original_key[0],(char)(original_key._0_4_ >> 8));
```

and here is the associated disassembly:

```
                     LAB_00101558                                    XREF[1]:  
00101558 0f b6 45 f1     MOVZX      __buf,byte ptr [RBP + original_key[0]]
0010155c 88 45 e4        MOV        byte ptr [RBP + local_24],__buf
0010155f 0f b6 45 f2     MOVZX      __buf,byte ptr [RBP + original_key[1]]
00101563 88 45 e5        MOV        byte ptr [RBP + local_23],__buf
00101566 0f b6 45 e5     MOVZX      __buf,byte ptr [RBP + local_23]
0010156a 88 45 f1        MOV        byte ptr [RBP + original_key[0]],__buf
0010156d 0f b6 45 e4     MOVZX      __buf,byte ptr [RBP + local_24]
00101571 88 45 f2        MOV        byte ptr [RBP + original_key[1]],__buf
00101574 c7 45 e8        MOV        dword ptr [RBP + key_index],0x0
         00 00 00 00
0010157b eb 42           JMP        LAB_001015bf
```

I can't figure out what this line of code is doing:

What I know:

original_key is a char[6]   i.e. it is defined as char original_key [6];
The value of original_key can be anything at the start of this line, but after execution original_key must contain the string 'uvxcuh'

What I think I know:

original_key.*0_4* means the 4 bytes starting at offset 0 of the original_key array (i.e. treat the first 4 bytes of original_key as an UINT)
CONCAT11 means append one byte from the second arg to 1  byte from the first arg.

what I don't know:

What this line is actually doing to the input. When i work through it on paper it doesn't make sense.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Ski

Comment: The C code swaps the last two bytes of the array.

Comment: I wonder what `key_index` is.

Comment: key_index is jst an integer which is 0 at this point.

Comment: @sim  Can you elaborate on how you figured that out?  When I work through it on paper for an input of "abcdef" I get a result of "abacef" which is wrong